# Profiles in Ubuntu

Tags: language-support

Ubuntu has profiles like Windows? If there is, for each profile can I set different language of interface? I hadn't used Ubuntu yet. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's of course possible. In settings You will find "user accounts" - right hand, bottom corner:
[image]

You can choose language while login in like in XFCE, or by choosing Keyboard Layout in classic Ubuntu with Unity just in Settings Manager

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you may add other keyboard layouts to my existing layouts. Open "System Settings" > Language Support" to see which input method is in use then do "System Settings > Keyboard Layout" and select another layout for the additional language(s).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

To add new profile:

```
   sudo adduser newuser
```

`newuser` = the name you want to give the profile

And a new profile will be created.  And you can make adjustment as you like per to your preference, language & even the customization like wallpaper or such.  You can find the keyboard setting in system setting and, once you saved your language in that profile, then Ubuntu will remember it.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you suggest a terminal command when "System Settings -> User Accounts" is available?

Comment: I often opt for command line as a habit when working on my scripts, so, I supposed that is a habit that got stick on me.

Comment: Ok, but please consider if that is a proper way to introduce a Windows user to Ubuntu.

Comment: well-noted.  Thanks @GunnarHjalmarsson